# How to count Upper-Case, Lower-Case and special characters

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to create a GUI in C#. In this GUI, I have a single text field and when I fill this text field, I would like to see how many Upped-case, Lower-case and special characters are used.

Comment: What had you tried so far? Where did you failed?

Comment: `int count = s.Count(c => char.IsUpper(c));` I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: What are special characters? Some likely useful functions are `char.IsUpper` and `char.IsLower`, but "special characters" is a extremely loose term.

Comment: What was your effort. Please feel free to edit it in your question.

Comment: For special characters you can use !char.IsLetterOrDigit or char.IsSymbol, but I am not sure what you understand as special character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About upper and lower take a look this.

```
 int upperCasecount = s.Count(c => char.IsUpper(c));
 int lowerCaseCount = s.Count(c => char.IsLower(c));
```

This is for the case of  special characters count.

```
 int numOfSpecialChar = s.Count(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c));
```

Comment: int numberOfSpecialCharacters = input.Count(c => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(c))
it's not necessary to provide additional operations as subtraction

Comment: @So_oP I haven't tested, but your last snippet is not valid c# to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Edited,I just done this a little bit quick.